# Absolute positioning on Firefox vs. Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I am having a problem creating a menu using jQuery that I have boiled down to the issue below. This sample code renders differently in Firefox and Chrome:

HTML:

```
<table id="topTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="outer">
                OuterDiv
                <div id="inner">
                    InnerDiv
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#topTable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}

#outer {
    background-color: Red;
}

#inner {
    background-color: Blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

In Firefox, the "outer" element appears 50px down the page, but the "inner" element is at the very top of the page. In Chrome, the "inner" div is slightly above 50px, but nowhere near the top of the page. Can someone explain why I'm seeing this different behavior? I noticed that adding "position: absolute" to the "outer" element causes the sample to render the same on each browser, but that messes up the styling on my actual menu code. If I could understand what's going on here, I can figure out what direction I need to take to fix my real code. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess it should come from their box model. I don't know more, but if your point is to have them behave identically, maybe using reset.css would do the trick.

Comment: I actually thought the same and tried to add YUI 2 reset to a fiddler, and while it did reset some stuff, it didn't fix the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/PN4UR/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `position:relative;` for #outer

```
#outer {
    background-color: Red;
    position:relative;
}
```

see : http://jsfiddle.net/5XWcD/1/, I tested in FF6.02 and chrome 11.0

Comment: To explain a little further: ABSOLUTE positiones the element to the last registered RELATIVE parent. If no relative Parent is defined, the mother of all (BODY) is used as reference. [[ Going by the definition of how it SHOULD work ]]

Comment: @Sam the containing block for `position: absolute` is the nearest positioned (whether absolutely or relatively) ancestor.  In the testcase above that should be the table, but Gecko handles that case wrong.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10209

Answer (score 1):

Set position relative in parent node

```
.classParent{
    position: relative;
}
```

And adjust top and left once again