# Div content aligned in Chrome and not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, angular10

I have an angular app, with an header divided in 3 sections. The top right section can contain the button login or the user profile icon if the user is already logged.

In Chrome the div content is centered.

[image]

But in firefox, the right_side_section div goes up.
[image]

The html file is

```
  <div class="right_side_section">
    <div class="header_btn" *ngIf="!isUserLogin">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn_right" (click)="openLoginModal()">Connexion</button>
    </div>

   <div *ngIf="isUserLogin" class="header_Profile">
          <div class="profile_img">
            <img *ngIf="appUser; else profile" src="{{ appUser.userPhotoUrl }}" />
            <ng-template #profile>
              <img  src="assets/media/image/profile/profile.png"/>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
          <div class="profile_padding">
          <div class="profile_details">
            <div class="profile_list">
              <div class="profile_details_img profile_adaptation">
                <img *ngIf="appUser; else profile" src="{{ appUser.userPhotoUrl }}" />
                <ng-template #profile>
                  <img  src="assets/media/image/profile/profile.png"/>
                </ng-template>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

and the css

```
.right_side_section{
  position: absolute;
  right: 34px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I noticed that the div.right_side_section is 50 * 90 on chrome and 50 * 65 on firefox.
Please, houw could i correct it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if u inspect the element, is there a difference in the DOM between Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: @DVN-Anakin, the difference i see is that the div on Chrome is 50*90. The image inside the div.right_side_section 50*60. On firefox the div.right_side_section is 50*65 and the image inside it 50*60. It is the only difference i see

Comment: What happens if you set `position: relative` for `.right_side_section`'s parent element (probably the whole navigation) ? More here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837929/absolute-positioning-on-firefox-vs-chrome

Comment: @DVN-Anakin i set the parent element to `position: relative` and works fine. Thank your very much